# rspec-sidekiq have_enqueued_sidekiq_job undefined method at

Tags: rspec, rspec-sidekiq

```
expect(MyWorker).to have_enqueued_sidekiq_job().at(Time.now)
```

causing me to get this error

```
undefined method at for #RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has:0x007fecb7f0a068`
```

Here are my rspec Gems

```
rspec (3.6.0)
rspec-core (3.6.0)
rspec-expectations (3.6.0)
rspec-mocks (3.6.0)
rspec-sidekiq (3.0.3)
rspec-support (3.6.0)
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass any arguments in `have_enqueued_sidekiq_job`?

Comment: My perform does't take any args, so I'm not sure what I should be passing. I also tried with no luck ` expect(MyWorker).to have_enqueued_sidekiq_job.at(Time.now)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it with require `rspec-sidekiq` in `spec_helper.rb`